# Why are my MergeField names the only data pulling through to a PDF via MailMerge in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I am currently trying to use the code below in VBA to bring data in a table into a mailmerge word document which then saves the individual merges as a pdf. The code almost does this but when I run the macro on my excel sheet the pdf's saved only bring through the mergefield names from the word document and not the data itself.

Any ideas on where I can go from here? I am currently using Office 2016.

```
Sub RunMailMerge()

    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, i As Long, j As Long

    Dim strWorkbookName As String: strWorkbookName = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|": StrName = "Easy.docx"
    StrFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    If Dir(StrFolder & strDocNm) = "" Then Exit Sub

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

    With objWord

        'Disable alerts to prevent an SQL prompt
        .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
        'Display Word - change this to False once the code is running correctly
        .Visible = False
        'Open the mailmerge main document - set Visible:=True for testing
        Set objWord = .Documents.Open(Filename:=StrFolder & StrName, ReadOnly:=True,
        AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)

        With objWord
            With .MailMerge

                'Define the mailmerge type
                .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
                'Define the output
                .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
                .SuppressBlankLines = False
                'Connect to the data source
                .OpenDataSource Name:=strWorkbookName, _
                                ReadOnly:=True, _
                                LinkToSource:=False, _
                                AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                                Connection:="User ID=Admin;DataSource=strWorkbookName;" & _
                                             "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
                                SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1                                SQLStatement:=", _
                                SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
                'Process all eligible records

                For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount

                    With .DataSource
                        .FirstRecord = i
                        .LastRecord = i
                        .ActiveRecord = i
                        'Exit if the field to be used for the filename is empty
                        If Trim(.DataFields("Tenant")) = "" Then Exit For
                        'StrFolder = .DataFields("Folder") & Application.PathSeparator
                        StrName = .DataFields("Tenant")
                    End With

                    .Execute Pause:=True
                    'Clean up the filename

                    For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
                        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
                    Next

                    StrName = "Letter - " & Trim(StrName)
                    'Save as a PDF
                    objWord.SaveAs Filename:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", _
                                   FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
                Next i

                'Disconnect from the data source
                .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
            End With

            'Close the mailmerge main document
            .Close False
        End With

        Call CloseAll
        Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
    End With

End Sub

Sub CloseAll()

    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

    objWord.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that you're either 1) not working with the mail merge *result*  that's been generated - instead your code apparently works with the main merge document OR 2) you're trying to use the main merge document but aren't correctly "unlinking" it. Which is your intention?

Comment: @CindyMeister If i set the code that makes the Word Documents Visable to true i can see that the mail merge works correctly and it opens multiple documents with different data but then this isnt being transferred to the pdf. hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is essentially a copy of code I've posted elsewhere (e.g. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/713478-word-2007-2010-mail-merge-save-individual-pdf-files-post4796480.html#post4796480), but why you'd add your call to CloseAll is a mystery.

Nonetheless, it's also clear you've also partially modified the code for use with late binding, by replacing:

```
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
```

with:

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
...
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
```

Had you stuck with early binding throughout, the code would work. Right now, though, your modified code employs a mix of late binding with named Word constants, which are really only applicable to early binding. You need to fully adapt the code to late binding or revert to code that is entirely early binding.

Comment: Thank you for this, i went back and managed to get it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to drive a mail merge via VBA code? You should be able to A) set up the data in Excel or Access, B) set up the template in Word & connect it to the data source, C) run the mail merge. Unless you're doing something really, really fancy, there should be no need for VBA.

Since it seems some sadist has forced you to do things the hard way, it looks like your error is most likely here:

```
Connection:="User ID=Admin;DataSource=strWorkbookName;" & _
            "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1
            SQLStatement:=", _
            SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
```

First of all:

```
Connection:="User ID=Admin;DataSource=strWorkbookName;" & _
```

should be

```
Connection:="User ID=Admin;DataSource=" & strWorkbookName & ";" & _
```

Second, your `SQLStatement` parameter is unterminated, and I'm pretty sure that `"Sheet1"` (not sure why you have an extra backtick in there) isn't the way to reference the "table" (i.e. worksheet) when selecting from an Excel workbook. IIRC, it should be `"WorkBook$WorkSheet"`, so this:

```
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1
```

should be something like:

```
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM " & strWorkbookName & "$Sheet1", _
```

That line is followed by the end of the string

```
            SQLStatement:=", _
```

which *was* part of the actual SQL string being sent to the database engine in Excel. That ain't gonna work.

The way I read it, that line should be:

```
Connection:="User ID=Admin;DataSource=" & strWorkbookName & ";" & _
            "Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
            SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM " & strWorkbookName & "$Sheet1", _
            SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
```

You may have to tweak it a bit, but I think that'll get you on the right track.

Comment: Still running into trouble, tried to insert this code and now excel freezes with the word doc trying to load. when i go into task manager word is open and it doesn't seem to be able to select the table now. In the select table section, the workbook path isn't working as it only selects the folder.xlms and not the workbook. Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you used `F8` to step through the code one line at a time to see exactly where it's hanging? That'll be your first step in figuring out why. I've _never_ put together a mail merge via code like this before, so I just pointed out a couple of things that jumped out at me as fairly obviously wrong. You're still going to have to dig into this yourself or wait for someone else to chime in.